# How do you change your chat username on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat, display-names

I changed my username on Stack Overflow to an actual name, but chat still says `user203948230948` or whatever. How can I fix this? I tried logging out and in but to no avail.

Comment: I figured it out. Need to change all accounts when updating.

Comment: IIRC your chat account is "linked" to one of your main accounts (the one you first used chat with?), and that's the one you have to edit.

Answer (score 3):

Your chat username is linked to the main site's account on a per site basis. So for meta chat you change it here on Meta, for Stack Overflow chat you change it on Stack Overflow and so on.

Keep in mind that changes you make to your main site profile take a while to reflect in chat, which is why your old username, reputation and badges might show for a while. They are usually out of sync by about 30-60 minutes.

Source: We had a couple of users in the Android chat room who's name changes and reputation didn't reflect for a while.